# Django , How can I set the default value to today of input date(not using forms)?

Tags: html, django

I'm using django to make website.
I succeded remaining the input date value after submit passing the value.
But I don't know how I can remain the selected value after submit. (I'm not using form)

Also, I want to know how I set the default value to today of input `type="date"`!

Here's my page. I want to keep remain the selected value after submit( after submit, the page return this page again)

[image: my page]

sales.management.html

```
<form id="sales_search" action="{% url 'management:sales_search' %}" method="GET">
    <select title="team_choice" name="team_choice" class="select" id="team_choice">
        <option name='FC' value="FC" {% if team =='FC' %} selected {% endif %}>FC</option>
        <option name='Fitness' value="Fitness" {% if team =='Fitness' %} selected {% endif %}>fitness</option>
        <option name='Pilates' value="Pilates" {% if team =='Pilates' %} selected {% endif %}>pilates</option>
        <option name='All' value="All" {% if team =='All' %} selected {% endif %}>all</option>
    </select>
    <span>Start Day: <input type="date" class="startdate" name="startdate" value="{{ startdate }}" ></span>
    ~<span>End Day: <input type="date" class="enddate"  name="enddate"  value="{{ enddate }}" ></span>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="search" >search</button>
</form>
```

I tried `{% if team =='FC' %} selected {% endif %}` in select boxes.

But, it gets error Could not parse the remainder: `'=='FC''` from `'=='FC''`.

views.py

```
def sales_search(request):
     team_choice = request.GET.get('team_choice','')
     startdate = request.GET.get('startdate','') 
     enddate = request.GET.get('enddate','') 
     #Todo ( it's a long)
       
     context = {
         .... ,
        'startdate' : startdate,
        'enddate' : enddate,
        'team':team_choice, }

    return render(request, 'management/sales_management.html', context)
```

How can I keep the selected value after submit and How can I set the default value to today of input date?

Any help will be very helpful to me, thanks!

Comment: I know that it has already passed more than a year, but I think, for the fisrt question, that you should use the statement "if request.method == 'GET'" and 'POST', to define whether you take the.GET.get arguments or POST.get; it could be helpful to keep the selected values.

Answer (score 1):

in your models you can add  DateField(default=date.today) 
references:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField

Answer (score 0):

you need to put a space between `==` and `'FC'` in your template.

And to set the default date to today in your views file add

```
import datetime
```

and in your context write:

```
context = {
     .... ,
    'startdate' : startdate if startdate else datetime.date.today(),
    'enddate' : enddate if enddate else datetime.date.today(),
    .....
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the space works!
But, I can't write the context like that, because there is already 'startdate' : startdate, 'enddate' : enddate because I have to remain the inputted date.  Is there another way?

Comment: where do you want to put the default date then?

Comment: <input type="date" class="startdate" name="startdate" value="{{ startdate }}" ></span>    & enddate  ! I want to show the today value as a default to the user.

Comment: @Julia see my edit. It will set startdate and enddate to `today` if no value is given in the `get` request. if you always want the enddate to `today` you can use `enddate: datetime.date.today()` in your context.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. I think it should show the today value before requesting.So I should change the template not view. Maybe making the 'today' value is the fastest one I can. If you have another way, please let me know. anyway thank you for your all answers and comments:)